# Enviar dados para URL externa através de formulário, com carregamento na mesma página

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Olá!

Sou iniciante em PHP e estou montando um formulário para receber dados através de POST, e imprimi-los em uma URL customizada. O objetivo do form é o cadastramento de leads em uma plataforma terceira de CRM, que só aceita a inclusão de dados desta forma.

A estrutura da URL é a seguinte:
https://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/api/Android/PutLead/< NOME >;< E-MAIL >;< TELEFONE >;< OBSERVACOES >/281/739164197

Aparentemente estou conseguindo executar o script e manipular o endereço, mas só consegui fazer isso com a função header("Location").

Formulário:

```
<form id="formulario" action="mail_lead_santos.php" method="post">
    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
    Telefone: <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone"><br>
    Motivo: <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
    <option value="Opção 1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="Opção 2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="Opção 3">Opção 3</option>
 </select><br>
    <input id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar!">
</form>
```

mail_lead_santos.php

```
<?php

 $nome = $_POST['nome'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
 $observacoes = $_POST['observacoes'];


$final = 'Location: https://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/api/Android/PutLead/'.$nome.';'.$email.';'.$telefone.';'.$observacoes.';'.'/281/739164197';

header($final);

?>
```

Com isso, após o preenchimento do formulário, naturalmente o usuário cai nesta URL final. De que forma eu conseguiria executar essa função através do formulário, mas mantê-lo na página de preenchimento? Entendo que a melhor forma talvez seja através de jquery/ajax, mas como trabalhar em conjunto com a função header?

Obrigado!

Comment: Considerando que a plataforma terceira valide os dados, acredito que, no seu cenário, a melhor opção seria fazer uma requisição GET com jquery mesmo. Sem a necessidade de recarregamento ou redirecionamento da página de preenchimento.

Comment: Certo! Não entendo muito de jquery, mas estou testando algumas coisas - postado como resposta na mensagem principal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta algo nesse sentido:

```
<form id="formulario" action="" method="get">
    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
    Telefone: <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone"><br>
    Motivo: <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
    <option value="Opção 1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="Opção 2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="Opção 3">Opção 3</option>
 </select><br>
    <input id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar!">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#formulario").on('submit', function (event) {

            var nome = $("#nome").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
            var observacoes = $("#observacoes").val();


            $.get( `sua_url_externa_aqui/${nome};param2;...`)
            .done(function( data ) {
                alert("Sucesso");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Erro" );
            })

            event.preventDefault();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Dessa forma você vai "parar" o evento de submit do form, pegar os valores e criar uma requisição GET para a URL externar que desejar passando os parâmetros na mesma.

Onde estão os alerts de sucesso e erro você pode, respectivamente, dar um feedback para o usuário exibindo uma mensagem de sucesso ou de erro, de acordo com sua necessidade.

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Como apontado pelo @Matheus nos comentários, estou fazendo um teste com jquery e GET - outro assunto que sou iniciante. Dei uma pesquisada e cheguei no seguinte resultado:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#enviar").click(function () {
            var nome = $("#nome").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
            var observacoes = $("#observacoes").val();
            var url = "https://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/api/Android/PutLead/" + encodeURIComponent(nome) + ";" + encodeURIComponent(email) + ";" + encodeURIComponent(telefone) + ";" + encodeURIComponent(observacoes) + "/281/739164197";
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>

<form id="formulario" action="" method="get">
    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
    Telefone: <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone"><br>
    Motivo: <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
    <option value="Opção 1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="Opção 2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="Opção 3">Opção 3</option>
 </select><br>
    <input id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar!">
</form>
```

Quando preencho o formulário, ele me devolve a seguinte URL: https://urldomeusite.com.br/?nome=Teste&email=teste%40teste.com.br&telefone=11999999999&observacoes=Op%C3%A7%C3%A3o+1&enviar=Enviar%21

Além de não enviar para a URL desejada e no formato certo, o formulário também está enviando o texto do botão de submissão. Outro ponto importante, como apontado pelo @Matheus, é que a plataforma externa valida os dados.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz, em algum dos caminhos? :/

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

@Matheus,

Obrigado pela ajuda! Editei o código e inclui dois campos hidden para enviar outras informações que preciso pela URL, e o final ficou assim:

```
<form id="formulario" action="" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" id="unidade" name="unidade" value="281">
    <input type="hidden" id="chave" name="chave" value="739164197">
    Nome: <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome"><br>
    E-mail: <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
    Telefone: <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone"><br>
    Motivo: <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
    <option value="Opção 1">Opção 1</option>
    <option value="Opção 2">Opção 2</option>
    <option value="Opção 3">Opção 3</option>
 </select><br>
    <input id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar!">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#formulario").on('submit', function (event) {

            var nome = $("#nome").val();
            var email = $("#email").val();
            var telefone = $("#telefone").val();
            var observacoes = $("#observacoes").val();  
            var unidade = $("#unidade").val();
            var chave = $("#chave").val();


            $.get( `https://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/api/Android/PutLead/${nome};${email};${telefone};${observacoes}/${unidade}/${chave}/`)
            .done(function( data ) {
                alert("Sucesso");
            })
            .fail(function() {
                alert( "Erro" );
            })

            event.preventDefault();

        });
    });
</script>
```

Após preencher o formulário, ele me devolve uma mensagem de erro. Fiz algo de errado na inclusão destes dados por hidden?

Comment: Se que o erro é "Cross-Origin Request Blocked": isso ocorre por que está tentando fazer uma requisição entre domínios diferentes, do _seudominio.com_ para _https://crm4u.azurewebsites.net_. Nesse caso, tem que solicitar quem administra o servidor desse terceiro, da URL externa, para adicionar o header [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) no response dessa URL externa.

Comment: Entendi! Aparece somente erro na mensagem aqui - vou dividir essa questão com o administrador do servidor e aviso por aqui! Super obrigado!

Comment: Vê se o erro que falei acima aparece no console do navegador. Ai terá certeza que é isso ou poderá descartar essa possibilidade.

Comment: Puxei, e apareceu aqui:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/api/Android/PutLead/Teste;teste@teste.com.br;11993388999;Op%C3%A7%C3%A3o%201/281/739164197/' from origin 'https://superalitoral.com.br' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Dividi a questão com o administrador do site por aqui! Obrigado mais uma vez!

Comment: Nada! É esse erro mesmo, mas escrito de uma forma diferente. Se puder marcar minha resposta como a resolução da pergunta, agradeço. Abraço!